# Increasing pomegranate production with second tree

Tags: fruit-trees, propagation, pollination, pomegranate

We have a single pomegranate tree we planted recently.  We’ve read that adding a second can greatly increase your harvest.  I assume this means more than just accounting for the extra tree.

How does adding a second tree increase fruit production more than just having a second tree?  If this is related to generic diversity, does it matter if the second tree is cloned by rooting a cutting from the first tree?  Should our second tree be from a garden center instead, or are these typically propagated by rooting cuttings anyway?

Answer (score 2):

Typically, if the second tree is *not* an exact clone of the first, better pollination, even with "self-pollinating" fruit types. Cloned is fine, but get a clone of **another variety of pomegranate**, not the same one you have now.